# How to retrieve metabase properties from within an ISAPI Filter

Tags: iis, isapi

In an ISAPI Filter, how can I retrieve [metabase properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525644.aspx) for the current application?

I know I can get the metabase path by retrieving the server variable `APPL_MD_PATH`.

How can I get, for example, the [PutReadSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525645.aspx) property, at runtime, within an ISAPI Filter?